# MVC6 CORE identity claims in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity

I am fiddling around with identity and I am definitely struggling - I have searched and searched, but nothing shows.

I want to add claims to identity and then be able to post these in the view on my page.

```
 public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var authenticationType = "Basic";
        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(await manager.GetClaimsAsync(this), authenticationType);

        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", this.FirstName));

        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
```

In my register user i save these with the user:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName};
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
                // Send an email with this link
                //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                //var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account",
                //    "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Note, that i checked my database and FirstName and LastName are being stored!

I then extended my identity *(Note i removed the original return, to check if it indeed returned null)*

```
 public static class IdentityExtension
{
    public static string GetFirstName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("FirstName");
        // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
        // return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        return claim.ToString() ;
    }


}
```

I now figured I should be able to access the data from my razor view, which is in **_Navigation.cshtml**

```
@if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <div class="dropdown profile-element">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                        <span class="clear">
                            <span class="block m-t-xs">
                                <strong class="font-bold">Hello @User.Identity.GetFirstName()</strong>
                            </span>
```

I also attempted to do this without the extension, directly:

```
 @{
 if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
     var FirstName = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("FirstName");
 } 
}
```

I am obviously missing something.. I can access the regular username without a problem. I have searched and found a lot to even get here, but a lot of it is different versions, so im stuck..

I'd appreciate if you can help me out!

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Follow here:
[Customizing Claims Transformation](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity)

Comment: [I think that links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/171858).